# Serving Angular2 at a path with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-mvc, angular, spring-boot

I'm running an Angular2 application inside of a spring boot app. This is my structure currently:

```
src/main
    java/com/test
        Application.java
    resources/static
        app/
        css/
        images/
        node_modules/
        index.html
        package.json
        systemjs.config.js
        tsconfig.json
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to tell Angular that I'm serving it from a path like so: localhost:8080/angularApp

I've got it configured on the spring side of things:

```
system.context-path=/angularApp
```

but I can't get the App to actually recognize that. Here are a couple of the things I tried:

Inside of the tsconfig.json:

```
"baseUrl": "./angularApp
```

Also inside of tsconfig.json:

```
"paths": {
  "app/*": [ "angularApp/app/*" ]
}
```

But neither of those are working.

when I try and load localhost:8080/angularApp

The issue I'm seeing is this:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/css/styles.css 404 ()
```

Inside of my index.html I've got it configured like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

If I configure it like this it does work, however that path may change based on the environment I'm running it in so hard coding every line like this isn't feasible:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="angularApp/css/styles.css">
```

I feel like this is supposed to be easy and I'm missing something.

Can anyone provide some insight?

Comment: Have you tried adding a base tag to the head of your index.html? <base href="/angularApp/">

Comment: @dmungin I did not, that was absolutely the entire problem. If you want to submit an answer I'll accept it.

Can't believe I missed that, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add a base tag to the head of your index.html

```
<base href="/angularApp/">
```

Link to the docs for further explanation if needed: https://angular.io/guide/router#base-href